# Google action test console don't let me run code in simulator

Tags: google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I am developing a chatbot application with google action console. I am new to google action. After deploying some dialog with it. It doesn't let me test app throwing Invocation error.

> **Invocation Error** You cannot use Actions deployed by others in the Simulator. If you want to try the Actions, use Google Assistant on
> your phone or other compatible devices.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question.
it was not about actions you have deployed, it was about the name that i was using for my app to run.
there was an another app running with same name because of that simulator was giving that error.